# Angular2 rc1 - Is order of @Routes declaration important (optional parameter)?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular-ui-router

Trying out the new Angular 2.0.0-rc.1 without the depracated stuff.
I want a component to work with or without path parameter. As I was unable to figure out the syntax for optional paramter (eg. `/detail/:id?` or `/detail[/:id]` would not work) I was left with the option to declare separate routes. Depending on the order I declare the @Routes, I'm hitting an exception

Why is this good:

```
@Routes([
  { component: HeroDetailComponent, path: '/detail/:id' },
  { component: HeroDetailComponent, path: '/detail' }
])
```

and this is not:

```
@Routes([
  { component: HeroDetailComponent, path: '/detail' },
  { component: HeroDetailComponent, path: '/detail/:id' }
])
```

When accessing parametrized url: `localhost/detail/1` I get an exception:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Component
>   'HeroDetailComponent' does not have route configuration

Component class for reference:

```
import {OnActivate, RouteSegment, Router} from "@angular/router"; 
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from '../model/hero';
import {HeroService} from "../model/hero.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'hero-detail.component.html',
  selector:    'my-hero-detail'
})

export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnActivate{
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService,
              private router: Router){}
  @Input()
  hero: Hero = new Hero();

  routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment) {
    if(curr.getParam('id') == null)
      return;

    let id = +curr.getParam('id');
    this.heroService.get(id)
      .then(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the order is important. More specific routes should come first, less specific ones last.

This is not intentional but a limitation of the current `@angular/router`.

It's currently not clear how they will move forward with the router. If you're just starting migrating from `@angular/router-deprecated` it's probably better to wait until the router strategy is made clear.